# Displaying streaming video in popup Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, popup, video

I have a GeoJSON with CCTV camera tags and links to m3u8 streaming video. I'm trying to open a streaming video from surveillance cameras in a popup on Leaflet, but nothing comes out. I don't know much about JavaScript.

```
var popup =   '<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264" poster="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png" data-setup="{}">'+
    '<source src="/sevmost-04_1920x1080.stream/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">'+
  '</video>';

var camers = L.geoJson(geojson, {
     onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        //layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.property0);
         
        //layer.bindPopup(function(layer){return feature.properties.property0},{maxWidth : 310})
        layer.bindPopup(popup , {
    maxWidth : 310
});
     }
 });
```

Comment: Do you know how to play streaming video outside of Leaflet environment, on plain HTML page?

Comment: I tried the library Video.js 8.3.0 everything worked for opening a video in a separate html page, but I do not know how to link it to leaflet.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification. This seems more of a pure JavaScript question, which might be better researched over in [so].

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger console or network section?

Comment: No, there are no errors

Comment: Can you use the browser DOM inspector and see if the element actually makes it to the DOM? Press CTRL-Shift-I or F12 to open the dev console and use the element picker (top-left) to check what element is actually in your popup.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Video.js player does not like to be directly wrapped inside Leaflet popup element/style. One possible solution is to declare video element at the `body` level, but wrapped in a `div` that will make it hidden and then then again wrapped in another `div` to get HTML element for popup content.

HTML part of the code could then look something like this:

```
<div style="display: none;">
  <div id="videoWrapperId">
    <video
        id="my-player"
        class="video-js"
        controls
        preload="auto"
        data-setup='{}' style="width: 300px;">
      <source src="https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL"></source>
      <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
        web browser that
        <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
          supports HTML5 video
        </a>
      </p>
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS part of the code could look something like this:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([52.2858, 5.78682], 14);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker([52.2858, 5.78682]).addTo(map);
var myPopup = L.popup().setContent(document.getElementById('videoWrapperId'));     
marker.bindPopup(myPopup);
```

This is the result of the above code:

[image]